# How do I get messages together with the authors with Telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I am using GetHistoryRequest to get all messages in a particular Channel. But it doesn't seem to save the authors of the messages. On the other hand, GetParticipantsRequest gives me all members by id, name, number, etc. Is it possible to combine them to give me member IDs together with their messages?

Comment: you can not get the `sender` of message sent in a channel, `from_id` will always return `None`

Comment: You also should consider using `iter_messages` instead. It's a lot easier than `GetHistoryRequest`, and the `sender` property will be set in megagroups (if that's what the question asks).